# Не показывать запись, если разница между временем двух записей меньше определенного интервала времени

Tags: sql, oracle, время, datetime

У меня есть список с клиентами и датой их покупки:

| id | time_ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:54 |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:58 |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 13:28:02 |
| 2 | 05.04.2021 11:02:54 |

Нужно вывести `id` клиента и время его покупки `time_`, но в случае, если покупка была осуществлена менее чем 2 минуты перед предыдущей покупкой, то такую покупку надо игнорировать.

Ожидаемый результат:

| id | time_ |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:58 |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 13:28:02 |
| 2 | 05.04.2021 11:02:54 |

Я попыталась с помощью `ROW_NUMBER` создать колонку, которая содержала бы номер следующей покупки и показывать покупки, где разница между временем предыдущей и последующей  покупки более 120 секунд, но столкнулась с проблемой, что при создании условия `difference_seconds> 120` в подзапросе `t3` изменяются значения `ROW_NUMBER` в `t2`.

Каким образом можно это исправить?

То есть, `SELECT * from t2` дает результат:

| id | time_ | id2 | time_2 | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:54 | 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:58 | 1 |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:54 | 1 | 05.04.2021 13:28:02 | 2 |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:58 | 1 | 05.04.2021 13:28:02 | 1 |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 13:28:02 | null | null | 1 |
| 2 | 05.04.2021 11:02:54 | null | null | 1 |

Но:

```
SELECT * FROM t2 
WHERE  difference_seconds>120
```

| id | time_ | id2 | time_2 | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:54 | 1 | 05.04.2021 13:28:02 | 1 |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 10:02:58 | 1 | 05.04.2021 13:28:02 | 1 |
| 1 | 05.04.2021 13:28:02 | null | null | 1 |
| 2 | 05.04.2021 11:02:54 | null | null | 1 |

Мой код:

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT id, time_
  FROM base_name)
, t2 AS (
  SELECT t1.id, t1.time_, t2.id AS id2, t2.time_ AS time_2,
    ROUND((t2.time_-t1.time_)*24*60*60,0) AS difference_seconds
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY t1.id, t1.time_ ORDER BY t1.time_ ASC, t2.time_ ASC) AS rn 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t1 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t2.time_>t1.time_)
, t3 AS (
  SELECT * FROM t2 
  WHERE rn=1
  AND difference_seconds>120
) 
SELECT * FROM t3
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вы хотите с  row_number добится? Посмотрите в сторону lead/lag функций.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте такой простой запрос (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4ef90ba90caf0a22f0a4a70384f3e7bb)):

```sql
with q as (
    select 
        q.*, case when (q.ts-prev) > interval '2' minute then 'y' end matched 
    from (
        select t1.*, lag (t1.ts, 1, date'-4712-01-01') over (
            partition by id order by t1.ts asc) prev
    from t1) q)
select q.id, to_char (q.ts, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') time
from q
where matched = 'y'
```

Результат:

```
        ID TIME               
---------- -------------------
         1 05.04.2021 10:02:54
         1 05.04.2021 13:28:02
         2 05.04.2021 11:02:54
```